# Unable to start program. sln - Visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2010 and tried creating the most common "hello world" program.
However when I try to run it I get the following message:
Unable to start program C:/... .exe
I saved the file as a work file with the suffix of .sln
I have already read plenty of threads but yet came to no solution.

I would be really thankful for you help

regards

Comment: your program is probably failing to compile. Why are you installing a 10 year old compiler?

Comment: @Evg I did compile it through the .sln, that created a .exe file, which apperantly cannot be found by the System

Comment: @AlanBirtles Because I have the Setup files of it. For the new ones one have to pay, regardless if one has already bought an older one. Why would it be failing to compile?

Comment: @Ozk the newest visual studio compilers are free.

Comment: Look for VS Community 2019. It is free.

Comment: If you look at the compiler output it'll tell you why it's not compiling. If you want us to tell you provide a [mre]

Comment: if there are no compiler errors, check for an executable. If it does not exist perhaps your Antivirus is the problem.